# OpenGL will only update the last vertex array object

Tags: c++, opengl

I am writing some code that generates some VAO and then when the physics have been updated a call is made to update the vertices inside the VAOs and then a call is made to redraw these objects.

The problem with my code is that only the last VAO is being updated by UpdateScene. The following two functions create the buffers.

```
void BuildBuffers(std::vector<demolish::Object>& objects)
{
    VAO = new UINT[objects.size()];
    glGenVertexArrays(objects.size(),VAO);
    int counter = 0;
    for(auto& o:objects)
    {
        if(o.getIsSphere())
        {
            BuildSphereBuffer(o.getRad(),o.getLocation(),counter);
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}

void BuildSphereBuffer(float radius,std::array<iREAL,3> position,int counter)
{

    GeometryGenerator::MeshData meshObj;
    geoGenObjects.push_back(meshObj);
    geoGen.CreateSphere(radius,30,30,meshObj,position);

    VAOIndexCounts.push_back(meshObj.Indices.size());
    glGenBuffers(2,BUFFERS);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO[counter]);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,BUFFERS[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                                  meshObj.Vertices.size()*sizeof(GLfloat)*11,
                                  &meshObj.Vertices.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, BUFFERS[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                                   meshObj.Indices.size() * sizeof(UINT),
                                   &meshObj.Indices.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT,sizeof(GLfloat)*11, 0);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,sizeof(GLfloat)*11,(GLvoid*)(3*sizeof(GLfloat)));
}
```

Then the following function updates the buffers when it is called.

```
void UpdateScene(float dt, std::vector<demolish::Object>& objects)
{
    float x = radius*sinf(phi)*cosf(theta);
    float z = radius*sinf(phi)*sinf(theta);
    float y = radius*cosf(phi);


    AV4FLOAT position(x,y,z,1.0);

    AV4FLOAT target(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    AV4FLOAT up(0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0);

    viewModelMatrix = formViewModelMatrix(position,target,up);

    for(int i=0;i<objects.size();i++)
    {
        geoGen.CreateSphere(objects[i].getRad(),
                            30,
                            30,
                            geoGenObjects[i],
                            objects[i].getLocation());

        VAOIndexCounts[i] = geoGenObjects[i].Indices.size();

        glBindVertexArray(VAO[i]);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                                0,
                                geoGenObjects[i].Vertices.size()*sizeof(GLfloat)*11,
                                &geoGenObjects[i].Vertices.front());
    }

    RedrawTheWindow();

}
```

The problem with this code is that it is not updating all of the buffers, only the "last" one. For instance if objects has size 3 then even if the locations of all three objects change only the last buffer is being updated with the new vertices.

I have narrowed it down to OpenGL but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) doesn't bind any array buffer object.
If you want to change the content of an array buffer, then you have to bind the array buffer:

```
GLuint VBO = .....; // VBO which corresponds to VAO[i]

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferSubData(
    GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0,
    geoGenObjects[i].Vertices.size()*sizeof(GLfloat)*11,
    &geoGenObjects[i].Vertices.front());
```

Note, a vertex array object may refer to a different array buffer object, for each attribute. So which one should be bound?

Since OpenGL 4.5 you can do this by the direct state access version too.
See [`glNamedBufferSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml):

```
glNamedBufferSubData (
    VBO, 0,
    geoGenObjects[i].Vertices.size()*sizeof(GLfloat)*11,
    &geoGenObjects[i].Vertices.front());
```

---

If the vertex array object is bound, then a named array buffer object which is bound to a binding point can be queried by [`glGetVertexAttribIuiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetVertexAttrib.xhtml) using the parameter `GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING`:

e.g.:

```
glBindVertexArray(VAO[i]);
GLuint VBO;
glGetVertexAttribIuiv(0, GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING, &VBO);
```

Comment: glBindVertexArray(VAO[i]);
       glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, BUFFERS[0]);
       glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                                0,
                                geoGenObjects[i].Vertices.size()*sizeof(GLfloat)*11,
                                &geoGenObjects[i].Vertices.front());

Comment: @HMPARTICLE Probably the `BUFFERS[0]` is worng. You've to use the bufferobject which corresponds to `VAO[i]`.

Comment: Ahhh so I need to STORE a pair of buffers for EACH VAO?!

Comment: @HMPARTICLE Yes, if you want to change the content of the buffer later, then you have to.

Comment: I understand now. I think my poor understanding of the graphics pipeline/openGL was at fault here. Thanks! it worked.

Comment: @HMPARTICLE You're welcome. Note, the array buffer object can be queried, see the last part of the answer.